# "Favourite Question" star not inline with vote options

Tags: bug, design

It seems the "Favourite Question" star isn't lined up correctly to the voting options.

I know it's minor, but I also know how much pride your designers take in their work. They wouldn't want this playing on them.

[image]

[*Source*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKBVS.jpg)

It just needs to to be pushed slightly right, and it seems this fixes/amends that:

```
.star-on, .star-off {
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

Comment: The zero does not align either.

Comment: I hope you're taking something for that OCD.

Comment: @Rudi - that's "I hope *you're* taking something for that OCD."  ;)

Comment: @J... - What ever do you mean? Cough. Ninja edit. Cough.

Comment: @Rudi that's "*Whatever* do you mean?" ;P

Comment: @J... You took the bait http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7459/can-whatever-be-split-into-two-words

Comment: @Rudi It's the least you could do after ruining my joke.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @Tanner, i know i know, but it's been in the corner of my eye due to weird screens at work that make it more predominant!

Comment: I can notice so clearly now, what has been seen cannot be unseen.  ;-;

Comment: Congratulations!  This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention.

Comment: @Mark, haha hold up, I'm not following :p

Comment: @canon The box for the star and for the rest of the upvote/downvote is formatted to the same size, so I don't think it's the bounding box that needs to be cropped by rather the actual image needs to be centered inside its bounding box.

Comment: It's "aligned" or "in line". "Inline" is something else.

Comment: Reminded me of this http://gizmodo.com/5788166/why-the-fck-is-the-1-on-the-iphones-calendar-off-center

Comment: That's what, about two pixels in your zoomed in image? How did you even notice that?

Comment: @immibis see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285487/favourite-question-star-not-inline-with-vote-options?noredirect=1#comment152349_285487)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1015/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed, and I hereby assure you that no pixels have been hurt during the fix (it will be live after our next production build).